# :src in vue.js is sending me error in GET method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the code in vue.js:

```
<b-img center :src="img" fluid></b-img>
```

And in the script:

```
img: require('../../../../img/quiz-background.png'),
```

Usually this is the way, that it worked for me, but today I have this error:
[image]

I know that it doesn't work because of `"/words/"`. If I would find a way to delete `"/words/"`, it would work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please add more code. we need more context. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Frankly, I would really love to, but the other code isn't related to this.

Comment: is this a vue-cli created project? and where is your image in? public? assets?

Comment: No, it isn't vue-cli and my image is in ``resource/img/``

Answer (score 0):

Try [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Like this:

`<b-img center :src="img.replace('/words', '')" fluid></b-img>`

or create another variable like

`var sterilizedImg = this.img.replace('/words', '');`
and then
`<b-img center :src="sterilizedImg" fluid></b-img>`

Comment: I had tried it, but it didn't work. It seems like it add ``/words`` after the image is loaded. Probably, that is why it doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide your result code?
need to ensure you did everything as I thought